# pd.to_datetime error after saving csv file without doing anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, datetime

when I was using pd.to_datetime, my code is like below

```
rate = pd.read_csv('P2training.csv', header=0)
rate['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(rate['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
rate.set_index('Date', inplace=True, drop=True)
rate.tail(10)
print(rate)
```

in P2training.csv, first column is 'Date' and this code ran well when I first downloaded P2training dataset. However after I open the csv file and save it without doing anything else, this code started to report errors below. If I put the original downloaded file to replace the 'saved' file, the code can still run properly.

> C:\Users\yaojia\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\compat\pandas.py:56:
>   FutureWarning: The pandas.core.datetools module is deprecated and will
>   be removed in a future version.  Please use the pandas.tseries module
>   instead.   from pandas.core import datetools Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\yaojia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py",
>   line 444, in _convert_listlike
>       values, tz = tslib.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)   File "pandas_libs\tslib.pyx", line 1810, in
>   pandas._libs.tslib.datetime_to_datetime64 (pandas_libs\tslib.c:33275)
>   TypeError: Unrecognized value type:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/yaojia/.PyCharmEdu4.0/config/scratches/scratch_7.py", line
>   23, in 
>       rate['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(rate['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')   File
>   "C:\Users\yaojia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py",
>   line 509, in to_datetime
>       values = _convert_listlike(arg._values, False, format)   File "C:\Users\yaojia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py",
>   line 447, in _convert_listlike
>       raise e   File "C:\Users\yaojia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py",
>   line 435, in _convert_listlike
>       require_iso8601=require_iso8601   File "pandas_libs\tslib.pyx", line 2355, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
>   (pandas_libs\tslib.c:46617)   File "pandas_libs\tslib.pyx", line
>   2484, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
>   (pandas_libs\tslib.c:44616) ValueError: time data '12/31/1979'
>   doesn't match format specified
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Could anyone give any hint what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you open the csv with excel? If yes, excel recognize that column 'Date' are indeed dates and parse the column in it's own date format (in your case 'day/month/year') and save it this way while you are expecting 'year-month-day'.

I suggest you to open/save your csv with a text editor or change the default excel date format...

Comment: the thing is the code works before until I open is and save again without doing any modification.